# jupyter-notebook markdown for multiline code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I know that in order to include code in jupyter-notebook as markdown (i.e not to be executed), it is possible to enclose it in this symbol (`)

The thing is this only supports short expressions that occur in the same line, what if I want to include something like:

```
def x(state):
    return state[0] == 'W'
```

And have it not be executed, and continue with the markdown. Is there a special trick for multiline code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use three `:

> GitHub flavored markdown
>
> The Notebook webapp supports Github flavored markdown meaning that you can use triple backticks for code blocks:
> ```` (```print "Hello World"```) ````
> Gives:

`print "Hello World"`

[see the Jupyter Notebook Docs on Markdown here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Working%20With%20Markdown%20Cells.html)

Answer (score 0):

use this markdown syntax will work in markdown cell in jupyter.

````
 ```python    
 def x(state):
    return state[0] == 'W'
 ```
````

`python` above is optional.